# Finding and removing autorun applications or services

Tags: 14.04, startup, services

Whenever I start my Ubuntu, there will be a `java` process by user `tomcat7` which eats up almost 200 MB of memory.

I think a few months ago I was fiddling around with apache tomcat for some spring/hibernate projects. But honestly I do not remember how did I install it.

How can I find out where this process/service/application is located and how to properly stop it from starting on startup without breaking anything?

Comment: Whats the output of `locate --regex '/etc/init(\.d)?/tomcat'`?

Comment: @heemayl it says `/etc/init.d/tomcat7`

Comment: So you could move that file or rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from the output of

```
locate --regex '/etc/init(\.d)?/tomcat'
```

`tomcat7` is using the legacy SysV style init and hence the start/stop script is in `/etc/init.d/`.

You can run the following command to remove all the symbolic links of `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` in `/etc/rc[0-6].d` (or `/etc/rcS.d`) directories so that `tomcat7` does not start automatically from next time you boot up the computer:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f tomcat7 remove
```

Comment: Thanks...before I execute this...I see in the man page of update-rc.d there is also disable/enable options. arent they safer if I ever want to enable it again?

Comment: @Saeid87 As per man page `enable`/`disable` is broken.. If you know the exact runlevels, you can use start/stop..also `remove` is not destructive, you can get back to original state just doing `sudo update-rc.d tomcat7 defaults` afterwards..